# How to include properties file in base class and then call to other classes?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng, testng.xml

In my application, I have properties file, where I added all the XPath of input fields. Through listener class I call base class, to take a screenshot for failed cases. And in testng.xml also I added the listener. Whenever I run the testng.xml, it shows "Null Pointer", which makes all the test cases as failed.

Note: In the base class, I have an initialization function which has driver, URL, log in details. And in other classes I included listener. Whenever I run,it shows "Null pointer".

```
Base Class:

public class base {

    public static WebDriver driver;

    public  void initialization() throws FileNotFoundException{

        Properties prop = new Properties();
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("./src/obj.properties");
        try {
            prop.load(fis);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    driver.get(prop.getProperty("url"));
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    WebElement email = driver.findElement(By.xpath(prop.getProperty("email_path")));
    email.sendKeys(prop.getProperty("email"));
    email.sendKeys(Keys.TAB);
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    WebElement pass = driver.findElement(By.xpath(prop.getProperty("pwd_path")));
    pass.sendKeys(prop.getProperty("pwd"));
    WebElement btn = driver.findElement(By.xpath(prop.getProperty("login_btn")));
    btn.click();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    }


    public void failed(String testmethodname) {

        File scrfile = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
        try {
            FileUtils.copyFile(scrfile,new File("./screenshots/"+testmethodname+".jpg"));
        }catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

Listener Class:
public class listener extends base implements ITestListener{
    // private WebDriver driver;
    public void onTestStart(ITestResult result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("TestCase started and details are "+result.getName());

    }

    public void onTestSuccess(ITestResult result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Reporter.log("TestCase Pass");
    }

    public void onTestFailure(ITestResult result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Failed Test cases are "+result.getName());
            failed(result.getMethod().getMethodName());

        Reporter.log("TestCase Fail");
    }

Example Class:

@Listeners(listener.class)
public class example extends base{
    @BeforeSuite
    public void setUp() throws FileNotFoundException  {
        initialization();

    }

    @Test(groups={"IV"},enabled = true, priority = 1)
    public void exam() throws FileNotFoundException, InterruptedException {
        Properties prop = new Properties();
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("./src/obj.properties");
        try {
            prop.load(fis);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        JavascriptExecutor jse22 = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        Thread.sleep(500);
        new WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
        .until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(prop.getProperty("path"))))
        .click();
        WebElement s = driver.findElement(By.xpath(prop.getProperty("a_path")));
        s.click();



        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
@AfterMethod
public void tearDown() {
    driver.quit();

    }

Testng.xml 

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "https://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite">
<listeners>
<listener class-name="pkg.listener"/>
</listeners>
  <test name="Test">
  <groups>
  <run>

      <include name="IV"/>

  </run>
  </groups>
    <classes>
     <class name="pkg.example"/>
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

Error:
Shows "Null Pointer" exception.

Comment: You need to provide you code and the error log.

Comment: I added the program.

Comment: which line of code/ method is throwing the null pointer. ? It will be easier to trace the issue from there

Comment: URL itself didn't open.

Answer (score 0):

It is bound to fail. `WebDriver driver` is never initialized. Before using get method, you need to tell which driver instance it is. Whether it is Chrome or Firefox or others.

Steps are as below:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","path//to//chromedriver//");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get(URL);
```

As the driver is never initialized it is `Null` and gives you a null pointer exception on failure.